# Copy Google Form Input to two different google Sheet tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form the information that is submitted is from students and faculty. The form has a trigger to run the function every time information is submitted. I want to copy all the submitted information to different tabs. One with staff members and one with student info. I can copy all the information into one tab, but when I try to separate it I am not able to get the results I need.

Any tips or guidance would be much appreciated.

```js
function copyRowsWithCopyto(){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Entrega_Dispositivos');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var studentSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Student_Copy');
  var staffSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Staff_copy');
  var lr = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:AS" + lr).getValues();
 
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
  var rowData = data[i];
  var status = rowData[2];
  
  if(status == "Student" && status != "Staff"){
      sourceRange.copyTo(studentSheet.getRange(1, 1));
  } else {
    sourceRange.copyTo(staffSheet.getRange(1, 1));
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for an onSubmit (single) approach or a batch operation?

Comment: For an onSubmit approach.

Comment: That's definitely a good application for google apps script.  Please provide more information about you desired output.

Comment: @Cooper I want the code to copy and paste the from entries into two separate tabs depending on if the information is Student or Staff.

Comment: I believe that you have you two answers please accept one of them by checking them off.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  const status = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (status === 'Student') {
    ss.getSheetByName('Student_Copy').appendRow(e.values);
  }
  else {
    ss.getSheetByName('Staff_copy').appendRow(e.values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put 2 queries, one in each tab, to separate student and staff, without any scripts !

Comment: I was going to go that route but, in my student_copy tab I am sending personalized emails to parents with information from our database.

Comment: You say "but" .. do you need a little more help? In this case, create a function to send emails, put a trigger on it and put a flag on the right to prevent multiple emails from being sent. Be carefull not to change anything in your main sheet.

Comment: I am gonna try this and see how it goes. Thanks for the tip.